# Store all details from a database into a file, and later download the file

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, download

```
protected void btnDownload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlCommand Command = connection.CreateCommand();
                    SqlDataReader SQLRD;
                    Command.CommandText = "Select *from Attendance";
                   connection.Open();
        SQLRD = Command.ExecuteReader();            
        string data = "";
          while (SQLRD.Read())
        {
            data += SQLRD[0].ToString();
            data += SQLRD[1].ToString();

        }

        SQLRD.Close();
        connection.Close();

        string filename = @"C:\download.csv";
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename,FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write);
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
        sw.WriteLine(data);
        sw.Flush();
        sw.Close();
        fs.Close();    }
```

This is what I have so far. I want to store all the data from the above query in a file. This file will be downloaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
protected void btnDownload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(@"Data Source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=PSeminar;Integrated Security=true;Trusted_Connection=Yes;MultipleActiveResultSets=true");

   MySqlCommand myCommand = myConn.CreateCommand();
   MySqlDataReader SQLRD;
   myCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Attendance";
   connection.Open();
   SQLRD = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
   string data="";
   while (SQLRD.Read())
   {
     data += "Row data, arrange how you want";//SQLRD[0].Tostring();-->first coloum
   }
   SQLRD.Close();
   connection.Close();

   string filename = "F:\file1.txt";  //with path
   FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write);
   StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
   sw.WriteLine(data);
   sw.Flush();
   sw.Close();
   fs.Close();
}
```

EDITED CODE: just copy paste in your code and change filename path

```
            MySqlCommand Command = connection.CreateCommand();
            connection.Open();
            //SqlCommand Command = new SqlCommand();
            MySqlDataReader SQLRD;
            Command.CommandText = "Select * from Attendance";
            //connection.Open();
            SQLRD = Command.ExecuteReader();
            string data = "";
            while (SQLRD.Read())
            {
                data += SQLRD[0].ToString()+"\n";
                data += SQLRD[1].ToString()+"\n";

            }

            SQLRD.Close();
            connection.Close();

            string filename = @"F:\download.csv";
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write);
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
            sw.WriteLine(data);
            sw.Flush();
            sw.Close();
            fs.Close();
        }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot! However, I still have an error at "string filename ="F:\file1.txt"; ", the error says unrecognised escape sequence,I do not understand this, how can I go about this error?

Comment: string filename ="F:\\file1.txt"; or FileStream fs = new FileStream(@filename, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write); any one you can do

Comment: can I ask one last question? I can only obtain one row of data, I wanna obtain 9 rows of data, how can I do this? Sorry to trouble you

Comment: in while loop i'm adding rows i.e., data+="some text" so for all rows it will append one row as one line it may be 1 row or 9 rows or more than that

Comment: thanks for taking time to answer my questions. but i cannot get all the the details from all the the 9 rows i have. so is there any other alternatives?

Comment: I have edited the question, I have changed to your answer, but it is still wrong

Comment: in query change '\*from' to '\* from' i.e, space is not there

Comment: there is already a space, it still download only one line, which is the first column of the datatable =/

Comment: k i checked this and adding in the current answer code check that

Answer (score 1):

Your code to save the data to file will change based on the file format that you want. Once you save the file, use [HttpResponse.TransmitFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12s31dhy.aspx) to push the file to browser. For example, the template code would be

```
protected void btnDownload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=PSeminar;Integrated Security=true;Trusted_Connection=Yes;MultipleActiveResultSets=true");

   string query = "SELECT * FROM Attendance";

   // Fetch data using data reader or data adapter
   ...

   // Save the data to file in required format
   string filePath;
   ....

   // Push the file from response
   Response.ContentType = "text/csv"; // set as per file type e.g. text/plain, text/xml etc
   Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=myfilename.csv"); // will prompt user for save file dialog, use inline instead of attachment to suppress the dialog
   Response.TransmitFile(filePath);
}
```

See other answers for code for storing the file in some format such as xml/csv.

Answer (score 0):

You would be best served by using serialization. I would create a structured object using the [Active Record](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/activeRecord.html) design pattern.

I would then output that object using XML Serialization to an XML object. I would then save that XML to the disk and deserialize it later and use it as if nothing happened.

See: [How to serialize and object to XML in C# on MSDN](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815813).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to write to file is using `DataTable.WriteXml` method which writes the entire data of data table to an XML file and this file later can be downloaded:

```
SqlDataAdapter sqlAdap = new SqlDataAdapter(query, connection);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
sqlAdap.Fill(dt);

string filePath = Server.MapPath("~/filename.xml");
dt.WriteXml(filePath);
```

But if you want to write this data to some particular format, say csv, you have to loop through all the rows and using `StreamWrite` class you can write it to file. The code below is just to give you an idea, i haven't added any type checking or checks for null.

```
string filePath = Server.MapPath("~/somefile.csv");
System.IO.StreamWriter sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(filePath);

foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows)
{
        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
             sw.Write(r[i].ToString());
             sw.Write(",");
        }

        sw.WriteLine();
}
sw.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can export it as a [DataSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.aspx) to disk like this:

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(@"<your conn str>"))
{
    var ds = new DataSet();
    using (var invoiceCmd = conn.CreateCommand())

    //One of these per table to export
    using(var invoiceAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(invoiceCmd))
    {
        invoiceCmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Attendance";
        invoiceAdapter.Fill(ds, "Attendance");
    }

    ds.WriteXml(@"C:\temp\foo.xml");
}
```